# Inequality involving an increasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, summation

Let $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ be an increasing sequence of numbers in $[0,1]$. I'd like to show that there exists a universal constant $ c > 0 $ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{i(n-i)}(x_{i+1}-x_i) \leq c\sqrt{\sum_{i,i'}(x_i - x_{i'})^2}.
$$
It seems plausible since we have the identity
$$ \tag{1}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i(n-i)(x_{i+1}-x_i) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,i'}|x_i - x_{i'}|.
$$
Edit: Proof of (1). Using the fact the sequence of numbers is increasing, we have
$$
\sum_{i,i'}|x_i - x_{i'}| = 2\sum_{i'\leq i}(x_i - x_{i'}).
$$
Next, $ x_i - x_{i'} = \sum_{j = i'}^{i-1}(x_{j+1}-x_j) $. Hence,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i,i'}|x_i - x_{i'}| & = 2\sum_{i'\leq i}\sum_{j = i'}^{i-1}(x_{j+1}-x_j) \\
& = 2\sum_{i'=1}^n \sum_{i=i'}^n\sum_{j = i'}^{i-1}(x_{j+1}-x_j) \\
& = 2\sum_{i'=1}^n \sum_{j=i'}^{n-1}\sum_{i = j+1}^{n}(x_{j+1}-x_j) \\
& = 2\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \sum_{i'=1}^{j}\sum_{i = j+1}^{n}(x_{j+1}-x_j) \\
& = 2\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j(n-j)(x_{j+1}-x_j).
\end{align*}

Comment: Are you sure about the first identity you claim holds? Trying with $(0,\dots,0,1)$, it seems off (in that case, by a factor 2).

Comment: Sorry, it was off by a factor of 2. I have corrected it. Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind adding the proof? (it seems worth having, unless it is standard enough?)

Comment: I added the proof. My main interest is whether (a variant of) the identity can be related to $\ell_2$ distances, as per my original question.

Comment: Clearly not as strong as what you want, but an easy one: by Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{i(n-i)}(x_{i+1}-x_i) 
&=
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{i(n-i)(x_{i+1}-x_i)}\cdot \sqrt{x_{i+1}-x_i}  \\&\lesssim \sqrt{x_n-x_1}\sqrt{\sum_{i,i'}|x_i - x_{i'}|}\\&\leq \sqrt{\sum_{i,i'}|x_i - x_{i'}|}.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Is c supposed to be independent of $n$?!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start.

The right side can be simplified.

Let
$s_1
=\sum_{j=1}^nx_{j}
$
and
$s_2
=\sum_{j=1}^nx_{j}^2
$,

$\begin{array}\\
r(n)
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nx_{j}\right)^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i - \frac{1}{n}s_1\right)^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i^2 - \frac{2x_i}{n}s_1+\frac1{n^2}s_1^2\right)\\
&=s_2 - \frac{2}{n}s_1^2+\frac1{n}s_1^2\\
&=s_2 - \frac{1}{n}s_1^2\\
\end{array}
$